# Rspec and commit callback giving an incorrect result

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a User and Role model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  validates :roles, presence: true, on: :save
  after_create_commit :assign_role

  private

  def assign_role
    self.roles << Role.client if roles.empty?
  end
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  scope :client, -> { where(name: :client) }
end
```

I can't get the following Rspec to pass:

```
  describe '#assign_role' do
    context 'when creating a new user' do
      it 'is triggered', test: true do
        user = build(:user)
        expect(user).to receive(:assign_role)
        user.run_callbacks(:commit)
      end
    end
  end
(#<User id: nil, email: "tester1@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>).assign_role(*(any args))
 expected: 1 time with any arguments
 received: 0 times with any arguments
```

I know the method is nit being called because I put binding.pry inside the method.

However if I change the callback in the model to after_create and :create in the rspec test it works

```
describe '#assign_role' do
    context 'when creating a new user' do
      it 'is triggered', test: true do
        user = build(:user)
        expect(user).to receive(:assign_role)
        user.run_callbacks(:create)
      end
    end
  end
```

I have even tried to turn off transactional tests with `self.use_transactional_tests = false` but it does not change the result.
I want to use after_create_commit instead of after_create.

How can I get this test to pass?

rspec 3.7, rails 5.2.beta2

Comment: Does build save the user or just build it?

Comment: Just builds it. Even if I change it to create(:user) I get the same erroneous result.

Comment: How do you have your DB set up for test mode? If it’s set up to roll back around each test it may not be committed at all.

Comment: But isn't this happening during the test, so rolling back after the test would not affect it would it?

Comment: I misread what you said. What I mean is that if the transaction wraps the test and it's rolled back after the test then it's never committed hence no commit hook.

Comment: I updated my question. I tried to turn off transactions for that test and I still get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164023/discussion-between-chell-and-dave-newton).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this gem 
`gem "test_after_commit"` for that, You might be thinking, “That’s weird. Why do I have to use a whole separate gem to test a callback that comes with Rails? Shouldn’t it just happen automatically?”

You’re right. It is weird. But it won’t stay weird for long.

Once Rails 5 update, you won’t have to worry about `test_after_commit`.

[please see this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18458)

Comment: This gem is only needed for Rails < 5. In rails 5.0 they have fixed the after_commit test problem